# Google Static Map Issue Marker duplicated

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-app-engine, google-maps-api-3

I'd like to know why is this error on this map:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=600x250&markers=size:lrg%7Ccolor:0x003087%7Clabel:1|5179%20LITTLE%20BETH%20DR%20N,BOYNTON%20BEACH,FL,33472&markers=size:lrg%7Ccolor:0x003087%7Clabel:2|8082%20ROSE%20MARIE%20AVE%20W,BOYNTON%20BEACH,FL,33472&markers=size:lrg%7Ccolor:0x003087%7Clabel:3|5065%20MARK%20DR,BOYNTON%20BEACH,FL,33472&markers=size:lrg%7Ccolor:0x003087%7Clabel:4|8639%20INDIAN%20RIVER%20RUN,BOYNTON%20BEACH,FL,33472&markers=size:lrg%7Ccolor:0x003087%7Clabel:5|8309%20LITTLE%20BETH%20DR%20W,BOYNTON%20BEACH,FL,33472&markers=size:lrg%7Ccolor:0x003087%7Clabel:6|8719%20INDIAN%20RIVER%20RUN,BOYNTON%20BEACH,FL,33472&markers=size:lrg%7Ccolor:0x003087%7Clabel:7|8406%20MICHAEL%20DR,BOYNTON%20BEACH,FL,33472&markers=size:lrg%7Ccolor:0x003087%7Clabel:8|5220%20ROSEN%20BLVD,BOYNTON%20BEACH,FL,&markers=size:lrg%7Ccolor:0x003087%7Clabel:9|8330%20THERESA%20RD,BOYNTON%20BEACH,FL,33472&markers=icon:http://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/159685/email-template-images/10.png|5321%20STEVEN%20RD,BOYNTON%20BEACH,FL,33472&markers=icon:http://www.cientificosdelsoftware.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/pin-1.png|5220%20ROSEN%20BLVD|8081%20ROSE%20MARIE%20AVE%20W,BOYNTON%20BEACH,FL%2033472&key=AIzaSyDRU-w01JB_mCSAv04tRQHlolkiGj4ep6I

(two markers instead of one)

Answer (score 0):

You have two addresses listed for the custom "large" marker (5220 ROSEN BLVD & 8081 ROSE MARIE AVE W,BOYNTON BEACH,FL 33472):

```
&markers=icon:http://www.cientificosdelsoftware.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/pin-1.png|
5220%20ROSEN%20BLVD|
8081%20ROSE%20MARIE%20AVE%20W,BOYNTON%20BEACH,FL%2033472
```

So you get one of those markers at each address.

Remove one of those addresses, and you only get one:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I missed that detail!